# Not understanding a C program

Tags: c

I have following C program and I am not understanding some point of this program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char ara[100];

    while(NULL != gets(ara))
    {
        printf("%s\n", ara);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If I input some string like **Hello World**, this code return me the output same as input. But, what is **NULL** and **gets**?? Are they from C library? Why their colour not changed when I compile them?

Comment: By colour, do you mean in your text editor?

Comment: It's interesting that you know C but not know NULL. Here is a site about C tutorial: http://fresh2refresh.com/c-tutorial-for-beginners/

Comment: @ Xymostech . Yes. Like **int**, when I type it, colour automatically changed.

Comment: The color in your text editor doesn't actually mean anything though. I could make a text editor that highlights `NULL` and doesn't highlight `int` if I wanted to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read [description of function gets()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/gets/)!
This function reads string from stdin. It returns NULL if found end of line or end of file before any characters.

Comment: Now that you have learned about `gets()`, **PLEASE FORGET THIS FUNCTION EVEN EXISTS** . It is dangerous to use as it has the potential to overwrite your buffer (in your case, if the input is more than 100 characters your program will crash). Next step on your journey: learn about `fgets()` which can be used safely.